# FetchError: network timeout at: https://db.fauna.com/

Tags: netlify, faunadb

I am currently using netlify to host certain logic in my application. I have read in the Known issues for faunadb, and explored solutions like declaring the instance of the object outside of the body of the function. I have tried the suggested solutions without luck. I am looking for alliterative solutions, because as the application grows, these errors become frequent.

```
const faunadb = require('faunadb')
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({secret})

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  //body of function goes here
}
```

Comment: What version of the fauna client are you using?

Comment: Any details you can provide would also help. Could you give an example of a query you run that causes a timeout? Are those errors happen unpredictably or you might see some pattern/timing?

Comment: I am currently using Fauna 2.14.2

Comment: The primary query being ran is a to get a list of schools Filter and paginate based on distance. The query itself executes fine, about 80% of the time. I have noticed failures on occasion when I first go on the site and enter an address to search. And when the page is not interacted with for a couple minutes and then trigger a search. The error is aways the one you see above.

Comment: Not sure, but it can be an issue with the server.
Could you try to use the latest version of the js-client, 2.14.2 is a pretty old one? The current version is 4.1.2. There's been http/2 support added and there were some fixes related to connection errors.

Comment: Just found this issue on fauna forum: https://forums.fauna.com/t/constant-http2-errors/1795
Can it be related?

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means certain this will help you, but I've actually been doing the opposite and including the Client object instance *inside* my Handler.

I was getting a lot of HTTP_TIMEOUT errors, so I moved everything inside the handler and the error stopped appearing.

Can't remember where I read about this, however. But it's worked so far!

Here is one of my Netlify function for querying FaunaDB, as an example:

```
const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { query, Client } = require('faunadb')
  const client = new Client({
    secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
  })
  
  console.log('Function `get-last-order` invoked')
  try {
    const response = await client.query(
      query.Paginate(query.Match(query.Index("orders_by_id_desc")), { size: 1 })
    )
    console.log('success', response.data[0])
    /* Success! return the response with statusCode 200 */
    return {
      headers,
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response.data[0].id),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
    /* Error! return the error with statusCode 400 */
    return {
      headers,
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    }
  }
}
```

Hope maybe this helps you.

Other thing to note is that there is a 10 second execution limit on the Functions. But if your function takes longer than 10 seconds to run, you should try to fix that first.